# How to get Text value of <legend> tag using xpath in ruby watir.(using IE)

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver, xpath-2.0

I have following code in my ie web page. I want text value of  tag (means "ABCD:"). I am using ruby watir for that.

```
<fieldset>
<legend class="fieldset">ABCD:</legend>
<fieldset>
```

I have tried with below code, but I don't why its not working and giving error(undefined method `text' for nil:NilClass)

```
ie.element_by_xpath("//legend[contains(@class, 'fieldset')]/").text
```

Is there any other way or is there anything wrong in my code.

Comment: a bit larger sample of the HTML might help

Answer (score 1):

Is that the only time the class of 'fieldset' is used on the page?

The [list of supported elements](http://wiki.openqa.org/display/WTR/HTML+Elements+Supported+by+Watir) shows unknown for Watir and supported for Watir-Webdriver for the legend tag.

Have you tried using Watir-Webdriver and code along these lines?

```
puts browser.legend(:class => 'fieldset').text
```

That's cleaner, easier to read, and will likely be faster.   Only resort to using xpath if nothing else works

Comment: Table of supported elements will get a facelift real soon. :)